# What is a brake handle on the ISS crew equipment carts?

Tags: iss

Outside the International Space Station, there is a device called a brake handle on the crew equipment carts. I couldn't imagine that device, what is it and what is it for?

I found it in the book of Scott Kelly, and also [here](https://blogs.nasa.gov/spacestation/2015/12/21/astronauts-make-quick-work-of-short-spacewalk/).

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26349/were-there-special-circumstances-leading-to-these-astronauts-spacewalking-5-day/26368#26368

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's to control the brakes on the cart, which follows a track that runs along one side of the ISS truss. The cart is named the Crew and Equipment Translation Aid. You can see what it looks like at [this URL](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/shuttle/f_slowtrain.html). Basically they can use the brakes to keep it in place and prevent it from moving.

[image]